# how to read data from firestore flutter by converting collections and nested documents into PODO(plain old dart object)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to read the data from the firestore in flutter. Is there ways by which we can read data from the firebase in flutter by converting into PODO(plain old Dart object).

Actually I need to read the nested data stored in firestore by converting into PODO.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to docs for how to access the data from Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart

Once you get the data, you can model that JSON object to a Dart object/model.